# Plotting from .dat file in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I am running a Fortran code that is outputting several sets of data to one .dat file. I want to plot the data, which is in two columns, using Octave. For example, the data I want to plot is in the following form:

```
      t              Eta(t)
     0.00           -0.748
     0.50           -0.773
     1.00           -0.774
     1.50           -0.535
     2.00           -0.120
     2.50            0.131
     3.00            0.184
     3.50            0.211
     4.00            0.068
     4.50           -0.110
```

Where the data starts on line 148 (not including the t and eta(t) line) and continues until line 247. The data for t and eta(t) obviously span across a few columns (according to the text file, that's where I'm reading the lines and column numbers from). Is there any way to plot the data if it's in this form by specifying which line to start from or anything? Put simply, I want to plot it so that the values in the t column are on the x axis and the eta(t) values are on the y axis. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much [faster](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Is-there-something-quicker-than-textscan-td4483991.html) alternative to `textread` (see Andy's answer) is `dlmread`.

```
filename = "yourfile.dat";
# empty separator means 'automatic'
separator = '';
skipped_rows = 147;
skipped_columns = 0;
m = dlmread(filename, separator, skipped_rows, skipped_columns);
t = m(:,1);
eta_ = m(:, 2);
plot(t, eta_)
```

If you want to stop reading the file after line 248, use

```
filename = "yourfile.dat";
# empty separator means 'automatic'
separator = '';
skipped_rows = 147;
skipped_columns = 0;
last_row = 248
last_column = 2
m = dlmread(filename, separator, 
            [skipped_rows, skipped_columns, last_row-1, last_column-1]);
t = m(:,1);
eta_ = m(:, 2);
plot(t, eta_)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this makes a bit more sense to me. I've actually managed to output it again just as a matrix so the data starts on the first line in the .dat file and I want to plot column 1 against column 2 (and then eventually column 1 against columns 3-6 as well). I'm guessing I can use this same format but don't need the skipped_rows and skipped_columns. Am I understanding that correctly? I am reading more about dlmread now so hopefully it'll be a bit clearer.

Comment: @user3306583 Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use textread. You want to skip 147 lines (headerlines) and read 247-147 = 100 lines

```
[t,eta] = textread ("yourfile.dat", "%f %f", 100, "headerlines", 147)
```

This will return 2 columns vectors "t" and "eta" with your data. After this you can plot them with

```
plot (t, eta)
```

Is you .dat online available or could you upload it?

Comment: Just looking up textread and don't quite understand it.. Will this command read that there are two columns and the values that i need are separate into those two columns?